Is Aira actually Acrobatic Silky’s daughter?
In Dan Da Dan, Acrobatic Silky follows Aira because she thinks Aira is her daughter.
This is because when Aira was really young, she saw Acrobatic Silky (who’d just died) and thought she was her mom, and didn’t want to leave her.
Then, her dad found her and pulled her away (didn’t see Acrobatic). It’s soon revealed that Aira’s mom had died before the encounter.
Later, back in present time, after Acrobatic sacrifices herself for Aira, Aira says to Acrobatic something along the lines of,

I was always happy when I was with you

In the flashback, however, Aira didn’t look like Acrobatic’s daughter. Yes, her hair could have been dyed and she was a lot older, but I’ve never seen an anime where colourful hair isn’t natural.
I also got the sense from the flashback that Acrobatic was a single mother, based on how we never saw a spouse, which wouldn't match Aira having a father.
Is Aira actually Acrobatic Silky’s daughter?

Wiki says she has an unnamed mother.

@FumikageTokoyami The wiki also says, “Aira felt sorry for the yokai upon learning from Turbo Granny that she would be forgotten by both the living and the dead once her body crumbled away into nothingness without her aura and ensured she achieved Nirvana by embracing her and acknowledging her as her mother”
